# Geometric sum converges to 1/2

Tags: real-analysis, summation, geometric-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3^{2^n}-3^{-2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I assumed this is a geometric series, but im not 100% sure about it. I checked if its convergent anyway, and it is, but other than that I cant prove it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. Limit when n approaches infinity of $x_n$ is 0.

Comment: The denominator equals 0 for even $n$?

Comment: I think it is $3^{-2^n}$ instead of $3^{(-2)^n}$

Comment: yes it is, i screwed up the mathjax

Comment: This is not a geometric series, but a telescopic series.

Comment: how is it telescopic

Comment: Have you posted the question exactly? I'm getting the sum going to 0.125.

Comment: does  it work if you start from n=0?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see that this sum is telescopic, rewrite the general term as

$$\frac {3^{2^n}} {3^{2^{n+1}} - 1} = \frac 1 {3^{2^n} - 1} - \frac 1 {3^{2^{n+1}} - 1}$$

Another way is to simply observe the partial sums

\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac38 &= \ \ \ \frac38 & & = \frac12-\frac18\\
\frac38 + \frac 9 {80} &= \ \ \frac {39}{80} & &= \frac12-\frac1{80}\\
\frac38 + \frac 9 {80} + \frac {81} {6560} &= \frac {3279}{6560}& &= \frac12-\frac1{6560}
\end{alignat}

and try to prove this observation by induction.

Comment: yes, thank you, i can apply the formula for telescopic sums from here, this was really helpful

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.